# Travis CI Timeout For Specific Jobs

Tags: travis-ci

I have a Travis CI based build and I have several jobs where one of them is supposed to push an image to a remote docker registry. Now at times this registry could not be available and in those situations, I would like to timeout this specific job, say after 10 minutes!

So here is what I have now:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
      script: sbt clean coverage test coverageReport
    - stage: build docker image
      script:
        - if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ]; then
            sbt docker:publishLocal;
            docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL;
            docker push $APPLICATION_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION_DEV;
          fi
```

I can see from the build logs that the build times out after 10 minutes which seems to be the default. But how do I override and set it to 5 minutes?

I could not find enough reference on the Travis CI website. How could I now add a Timeout to the build docker stage above?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `travis_wait` Bash function to achieve what you want e.g.

```
travis_wait 5 docker push $APPLICATION_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION_DEV;
```

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received

Answer (score 1):

There are several options/ideas you can explore when using `travis_wait`:

1. Export the `travis_wait` function and use it within your bash scripts

   ```
   scripts:
    - export -f travis_wait
    - cat./scripts/yours-using-travis_wait.sh | sudo bash -s $SOME_VAR
   ```
2. Use `travis_wait` directly in the travis-ci script step

   ```
   scripts:
    - travis_wait 90 make install
      # OR
    - travis_wait 90 sleep infinity & 
    - cat./scripts/yours.sh | sudo bash -s $SOME_VAR
      # OR in some cases this "quoting" has worked
    - "travis_wait 90 sleep infinity&"
    - curl --funky-stuff-here
   ```